# Selenium scraping not right tab

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I got 2 tabs opened in selenium, the script is working in the second one. When I want to execute

```
link = self.webdriver.current_url
```

I receive a link to the first tab(unused). How can I scrape the link of the tab where the automation is running?

Answer (score 1):

To get the link of the current tab do:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
link = driver.current_url
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[<tab number>])
```

Please note that list indexing starts from 0 in python, so the first tab would be index 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `switch` to window to access the element.

Let's say you have two tab and you want to access second window so to access the second window use

```
self.webdriver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
link = self.webdriver.current_url
```

do some operation

Now if you want to back to `first tab`

```
self.webdriver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```